# C++ Library for TCP/IP Like WebClient/HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c++, tcp, httpwebrequest, webclient

Is there any C++ Library that can download data from internet when we provide a URL? I am currently learning C++ and wish to start from making use of such library in my application. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).